# Swift crash in swift_getSingletonMetadata, "type metadata accessor"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I've been getting some weird crash logs from my Mac app. Here's the crashed thread:

```
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G103)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_MAPERR at 0x0
Crashed Thread:  8

Thread 8 Crashed:
0   ???                                  0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
1   libswiftCore.dylib                   0x00007fff79a743f3 swift_getSingletonMetadata + 578
2   PowerPhotos                          0x000000010323f30d type metadata accessor for PowerPhotos.IPAssetCollectionUpdate (<compiler-generated>:0)
3   libswiftCore.dylib                   0x00007fff79a8c94c swift::TargetProtocolConformanceDescriptor<swift::InProcess>::getCanonicalTypeMetadata() const + 171
4   libswiftCore.dylib                   0x00007fff79a8da24 swift_conformsToSwiftProtocolImpl(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, llvm::StringRef) + 291
5   libswiftCore.dylib                   0x00007fff79a8d884 swift_conformsToProtocolImpl(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*) + 99
6   PowerPhotos                          0x000000010339e7a9 swift::swift50override_conformsToProtocol(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const* (*)(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*)) + 56
7   libswiftCore.dylib                   0x00007fff79a6215a swift::_conformsToProtocol(swift::OpaqueValue const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptorRef<swift::InProcess>, swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const**) + 41
8   libswiftCore.dylib                   0x00007fff79a65f97 _conformsToProtocols(swift::OpaqueValue const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetExistentialTypeMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const**) + 230
9   libswiftCore.dylib                   0x00007fff79a65369 _dynamicCastToExistential(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetExistentialTypeMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::DynamicCastFlags) + 488
10  libswiftCore.dylib                   0x00007fff79836517 Swift._print_unlocked<A, B where B: Swift.TextOutputStream>(A, inout B) -> () + 550
11  PowerPhotos                          0x00000001031e2483 PowerPhotos.IPArchiveUpdateOperation.(loadFromReplay in _C3BCBD43848FA0F2A85DA8591115A6A7)() -> PowerPhotos.IPArchiveLoadResult (<compiler-generated>:0)
12  PowerPhotos                          0x00000001031e1700 PowerPhotos.IPArchiveUpdateOperation.(loadFromPreferredDatabase in _C3BCBD43848FA0F2A85DA8591115A6A7)() -> (PowerPhotos.IPArchiveLoadResult, Swift.Error?) (IPArchiveUpdateOperation.swift:430)
13  PowerPhotos                          0x00000001031e08fa PowerPhotos.IPArchiveUpdateOperation.perform() throws -> Any (IPArchiveUpdateOperation.swift:218)
14  PowerPhotos                          0x00000001031e179c @objc PowerPhotos.IPArchiveUpdateOperation.perform() throws -> Any (<compiler-generated>:0)
15  BWFoundation                         0x00000001036c8173 -[BWOperation main] (BWOperation.m:124)
16  PowerPhotosKit                       0x0000000103898e71 -[IPOperation main] (IPOperation.m:287)
17  Foundation                           0x00007fff502f5ced -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 684
18  Foundation                           0x00007fff5031fca7 __NSOQSchedule_f + 226
19  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fff7a0055f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11
20  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fff7a00663d _dispatch_client_callout + 7
21  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fff7a008de6 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 413
22  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fff7a0084a3 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 702
23  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fff7a0143bc _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 323
24  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fff7a014b46 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 89
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00007fff7a2466b3 _pthread_wqthread + 582
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00007fff7a2463fd start_wqthread + 12
27  ???                                  0x0000000054485244 0x0 + 0
```

Frame 11 is the last time my own code is seen, that line of code looks like this:

```
return IPArchiveLoadResult(error: NSError(description: "Replay did not complete \(replayDatabase.replayState.debugDescription)"))
```

So it looks like the call to debugDescription is what's generating the rest of the stack trace, to create that interpolated string. This ultimately ends up in frame 3 which references 'type metadata accessor for PowerPhotos.IPAssetCollectionUpdate'.

But here's the weird thing: IPAssetCollectionUpdate has absolutely nothing to do with the code that's calling this stuff. It's in an entirely different part of the application. So I think it's mostly coincidental that this is triggering whatever metadata loading Swift is doing here.

Looking at IPAssetCollectionUpdate, I think I see what's probably tripping it up:

```
@available(OSX 10.15, *)
struct IPAssetCollectionUpdate {
    let assetCollection: PHAssetCollection
    let diff: CollectionDifference<PHAsset>
}
```

Notice that IPAssetCollectionUpdate is marked as available only on macOS 10.15, and the crashes are all occurring on macOS 10.14. PHAssetCollection and PHAsset do exist on macOS 10.14, but CollectionDifference does not. This isn't a problem in the rest of the app, since everything's protected by the @available directive, but it seems that the Swift runtime is still trying to dig into this struct and generate some internal metadata and blowing up when it can't handle CollectionDifference. Or something like that?

Anyway, that's the setup, so my questions are:

1. Should this be considered a Swift bug? It seems like with everything properly annotated with availability directives, I should be able to ship this on macOS 10.14 and not have things crash, since I'm never actually using this struct at all on 10.14.
2. Regardless of whose fault it is, is there any way I can change this code so that it doesn't blow up on 10.14? The best I can think of is to break it out into a loadable bundle in my app and load the bundle manually when running on 10.15. That seems like a lot of work for this silly problem though, and I'd like to know if there's some other simpler way to handle this.

I'm compiling this using Xcode 11.5 and Swift 5.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Stack Overflow was a good rubber duck for me here, I was able to avoid the crash by doing the following:

```
struct IPAssetCollectionUpdate {
    let assetCollection: PHAssetCollection
    let typeErasedDiff: Any

    var diff: CollectionDifference<PHAsset> {
        return self.typeErasedDiff as! CollectionDifference<PHAsset>
    }
}
```

It's terrible, but it works. But my question about whether this should be considered a Swift bug remains, and whether there's a more sanctioned way to write this type of code.